# set correct column names when output list items to csv in r

Tags: r, output

Given a list (e.g. out), I want to write each item out to a separate csv file for use elsewhere. 
The list is large and contains a lot of items so I wanted to shortcut using a for loop. I created the following to
build a name for each output file based on the data group and date. When I run it everything works except it renames the columns
using the list item name and the existing colnames (e.g. instead of 'week4' I get 'pygweek4'. I do not want it to change my column names.

I tried setting col.names = TRUE, hoping to retain the existing names, and using the code below to specify the names, 
as well as setting col.names = FALSE. In all cases I get a warning message saying that "attempt to set 'col.names' ignored".

Can anyone suggest a simple method of retaining the column names I already have?

```
out <- list(pyg = structure(list(week4 = c("0", "1", "1", "0", "1"), 
      week5 = c("0", "1", "1", "1", "1"), week6 = c("0", "1", "0", "1", "1"), 
      week7 = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1"), week8 = c("0", "1", "0", "1", "1")), 
      row.names = 281:285, class = "data.frame"), 
      saw = structure(list(week4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
      week5 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), week6 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
      week7 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), week8 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1")), 
      row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")) 

 for(i in 1:length(out)){
  n = paste(paste(names(out)[i],Sys.Date(), sep = "_"),  ".csv", sep = "")  # create set name and version control
  write.csv(out[i], file = n, row.names = FALSE, col.names = c("week4", "week5", "week6", "week7", "week8"))
}
```

Sorry for the lack of decent tags... I don't have the reputation to set tags that I think are useful for this post and couldn't find ones that made sense in the ones available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need to specify the `col.names`.  The issue seems to be that, the `list` elements are not extracted correctly. It should be `[[i]]` instead of `[i]`.  With `[i]`, it is still a `list` of one `data.frame` element.  By doing `[[i]]`, it extracts the `data.frame` from the `list`

```
for(i in seq_along(out)){
   n <- paste(paste(names(out)[i],Sys.Date(), sep = "_"),  
                     ".csv", sep = "")  
    write.csv(out[[i]], file = n, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
   }
```

The difference can be found from checking the `str`

```
str(out[[1]])
str(out[1])
```